# What does generator() do within the code of blogdown::serve_site?

Tags: r, blogdown

I am trying to understand how the function `blogdown::serve_site` works. Its code, in R console, is shown as below:

```
> blogdown::serve_site
function (..., .site_dir = NULL) 
{
    serve = switch(generator(), hugo = serve_it(), jekyll = serve_it(baseurl = get_config2("baseurl", 
        ""), pdir = get_config2("destination", "_site")), 
        hexo = serve_it(baseurl = get_config2("root", ""), 
            pdir = get_config2("public_dir", "public")), 
        stop("Cannot recognize the site (only Hugo, Jekyll, and Hexo are supported)"))
    serve(..., .site_dir = .site_dir)
}
<bytecode: 0x000002919ec4f158>
<environment: namespace:blogdown>
```

Within the `switch` function, the function `generator()` does not seem to be either a base-R function or a blogdown function. Its code can not be viewed through the R console. What does this function `generator()` do and how can I view its code?

Comment: Just a guess but it's probably an internal blogdown function. You can use triple colons to directly get at it blogdown:::generator

Comment: Alternatively just use getAnywhere("generator") and it will tell you where it's from

Comment: Thank you so much, @Dason! Indeed, it is an internal blogdown function, and blogdown:::generator displays its code. However, the code is written using other internal blogdown functions, and it is not immediately apparent what the function actually does from viewing the code. I am trying to understand it. I didn't know about the functions of the triple colons, and about the getAnywhere function. Particularly, the getAnywhere function is really useful! Thank you again!